SharePoint REST API returns invalidRequest apiNotFound when registering Container Type
I am trying to call the SharePoint REST API to register a new SharePoint Embedded Container Type. I'm following the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-embedded-setup/5-exercise-setup-configure-sharepoint-embedded
Instead of PostMan, I'm trying to do implement the container type registration in C#, so my application can do it automatically.
At first I tried to map the pre-request JavaScript in the tutorial to C#, but then I realized I can use MSAL to get the necessary access token. At least I don't get any authentication errors when I use the token generated like this:
X509Certificate2 appCertificate = GetAppCertificate();

IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create( this.Configuration.ClientAppId )
    .WithTenantId( this.Configuration.ConsumingTenantId )
    .WithCertificate( appCertificate )
    .Build();
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient( new List<string> { this.Configuration.RootSiteUrl + "/.default" } )
    .ExecuteAsync();
return authenticationResult.AccessToken;

But when I try to invoke the container type registration URL:
string payload = $$"""
    {
      "value": [
        {
          "appId": "{{this.Configuration.ClientAppId}}",
          "delegated": ["full"],
          "appOnly": ["full"]
        }
      ]
    }
    """;

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Bearer", token );

string url = $"{this.Configuration.RootSiteUrl}/_api/v2.1/storageContainerTypes/{this.Configuration.ContainerTypeId}/applicationPermissions";
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync( url, new StringContent( payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" ) );

I get an error with the code apiNotFound. At first I thought I may not have enabled the SharePoint embedded feature in my SharePoint instance. But I didn't find the relevant setting at all, and the video that mentioned the need to set that setting also said setting is only needed while the feature is in preview, so I presume it is now enabled by default.
The only reference to "SharePoint apiNotFound" I was able to find was this: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/9081. But it talks about a typing issue in the GraphAPI, I'm talking to the raw SharePoint REST API.

Okay, as so often, this was a tiny stupid mistake by the author. The Container Type Registration is a PUT operation, not POST:
var response = await httpClient.PutAsync( url, new StringContent( payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" ) );

API not found is a perfectly sensible error message when there is no routing for the HTTP method used. Well, at least there is now one search result pointing this out.

Thanks for asking and answering. I'd mark it correct if I could.
